# Lubuntu allow non-admin to mount drive without admin password

Tags: partitioning, mount, lubuntu, password, ntfs

Question 1:
I'm the administrator of my Lubuntu system. I only have one "Desktop User" account for all kids. But when ever the Desktop User tries to access or open the "Data"[NTFS partition](Drives where movies, pics, songs and other files are stored) it asks for the Administrator's password. I created the user account for all my other family members and I don't want to tell them my password.

So is it possible to allow them to access the "Data" NTFS partition without asking Administrator's password ? it says "Authentication is required to Mount (/dev/sdc7)"

Question 2:
i'm on lubuntu 14.4.0 (by the way how to check my installed lubuntu version?) and will it update from SOFTWARES & UPDATES it self or i'll always need to CLEAN FORMAT INSTALL a never version everytime?

NOTE:
please provide a screen tutorial how to fix the "Question 1" because lubuntu is my 1st linux ever. and I'm a novice user. just installed yesterday.

SOLVED Question 1:
in DISK App on NTFS Partition. i Turned On Auto Mount and then added "users" in the Text bar displaying codes. And it works now :-)

Comment: If you have multiple questions, please post them separately. You can edit the question.

Comment: Don't add solved in your question, accept the answer that solved your question instead.

Comment: @Alvar won't adding [SOLVED] make it easier for people to find the solution who use Search option within website or on google.com? landing more hits to the question and answer directly all together?

Comment: not on this site, a solved question is marked in green in the search list on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `users` mount option in its `/etc/fstab` entry.  That lets regular users mount and unmount the partition without a password.

[Reference](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/mount-options-users-vs-user-670873/)

Comment: can you show photo screen shot of this how to do it??

Comment: Look for this:

`/dev/sda2 /media/mountpoint ntfs-3g noauto,users,uid=bill,gid=users,file_mode=0644,rw 0 0`

Replace `/dev/sda2` with your partition and `/media/mountpoint` with where you want to mount it.
Replace `uid=bill` with your desired owner of the mountpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Give your user account an entry in `/etc/sudoers` to use mount. Or you could always mount ntfs partition at boot time by adding a line to the end of `/etc/fstab`. First create a directory in `/mnt` and alter permissions and ownership using [`chmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/chmod.1.html) and [`chown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/chown.1.html). Add the line to `fstab`, reboot and test.

The fstab method will be best.

As root or [via `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo):

1. Create a directory to mount `sdc7` to.
2. Alter new directory's permissions and ownership.
3. Mount `sdc7` to new directory.
4. Using [`su`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/su.1.html) check that users can access the file system.
5. Enter command `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`, note the UUID of `sdc7`.
6. Open [`/etc/fstab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/fstab.5.html) in a text editor. Each line is a record, fields separated by tabs. Add new line reading something like:

   ```
   UUID={uuid@5} {path of @1} ntfs defaults 0 3
   ```
7. Save and reboot your system, if the boot sequence reports unable to mount... the UUID is probably wrong.

(If you're new, commands [`apropos`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/apropos.1.html) and [`man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/man.1.html) will help.)

Comment: You might want to add the `users` mount option here...